# It is possible rebuild an Assembly with source code from referencesource.microsoft.com?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm curious as to whether there it is possible to rebuild the assembly as PresentationFramework.

My goal is to improve and adapt the `richTextBox` control Because I could not find any way to the control will give my needs without changing the source code.

It could be something very wonderful if it were possible for everyone to take the source code as a starting point and continue developing the controls according to his needs, it would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the download section of the site [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) you can read

> Download the entire source code of .NET Framework as a .zip file. The
>   archive includes a solution and project files that can be opened in
>   Visual Studio. **This solution will not build because it is missing
>   crucial components such as resources, XAML files, etc.** but it will be
>   sufficient to browse the source code inside Visual Studio.

And in the License section you can also read

> "Reference use" means use of the software within your company as a
>   reference, in read only form, for the sole purposes of debugging your
>   products, maintaining your products, or enhancing the interoperability
>   of your products with the software, and specifically excludes the
>   right to distribute the software outside of your company.

So, I think that will be a waste of time just trying....